# Simple Alignment to the Left

Tags: support, mathjax

Yesterday I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079251/chevron-symbols-in-commutator) followed by a Post Script. How do I align the equations in the Post Script by the "=" signs, just like "someone you know" did when responding to me? The following is the equations' code:

> S_1 = {hgh^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H } 
> = {hg (g^{n-1})(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H } 
> = {h(g g^{n-1})(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H } 
> = {hg^n(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} \mid h \in H }

Thank you for your time and happy holidays to all.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18826/ability-to-view-answers-in-latex/

Answer (score 4):

If you see any MathJax code on this site, you can right click and choose "Show Math As/TeX Commands".

[image: Show Math As]

(The picture is taken from [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/accessing-a-latex-code-from-comments-to-incorporate-it-in-the-answer/5074#5074) on http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com. See also [demo on MathJax website](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/copy-and-paste/).)

In [this particular case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079251/chevron-symbols-in-commutator/1079253#1079253), you will get

```
\begin{align*}
S_1&=\{hgh^{-1}g^{-1}:h\in H\}\\
S_2&=\{hkh^{-1}k^{-1}:h\in H,k\in\langle g\rangle\}=\{hg^nh^{-1}g^{-n}:h\in H, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align*}
```

$\begin{align*}
S_1&=\{hgh^{-1}g^{-1}:h\in H\}\\
S_2&=\{hkh^{-1}k^{-1}:h\in H,k\in\langle g\rangle\}=\{hg^nh^{-1}g^{-n}:h\in H, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align*}$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!