# Viewing markup of question/answer/comment, of one for which is editing is not allowed.

Tags: feature-request, editing, markdown-preview

Is there a way to see the markup of questions/answers/comments for which editing is not allowed?

[This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/482/569197) says to right-click and select `Show source`. It looks like this method doesn't exist anymore, using Firefox at least.

The page's source html can be seen from Firefox's Web Developer menu. This allows to see the MathJax, but other Markup formatting has been replaced by the text being structured using the html tags.

Using the `edit` link in questions allows to see the original Markdown. Although, this sometimes doesn't work when there is a suggested edit awaiting approval. It looks like other people's answers  also don't show the Markdown by pressing edit. Finally, comments lose the edit link after some time. I wonder why editing doesn't get disallowed upon submitting instead of upon request. For example, a question/answer/comment could keep its `edit` link functioning and showing the source Markdown, while not allowing the edit to be submitted, and perhaps displaying a message that edits will not be accepted.

Comment: On a very recent version of Firefox (62.0b4), this is still quite possible - just right click on the rendered MathJax, follow "Show Math As" and then click the appropriate button for TeX commands.

Comment: If you right-click on MathJaxified mathematics, you can select the option `Show Math as... > MathML Code` or `> TeX Commands`.  Beyond that, I am not sure that there is much that you can do, though this sounds like an XY Problem.  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes, ways to see the MathJax there are. I mentioned it above. Do you know how to see the rest of the Markdown?

Comment: @XanderHenderson See the comment above.

Comment: Try not using the mobile app. Its features are more emaciated than their counterparts on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *posts* you can go first to revision history of the specific post. And after that click on view source. This was suggested in this answer: [Can you copy paste tex code from the question without going the “view source” route?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217#1218)

How to get to the revision history: If the post in question was edited it suffices to click on the timestamp. But for any post (edited or not) the link of the form `http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/{id}/revisions` works, where `{id}` is the id of the post. (And of course `math.stackexchange.com` has to be replaced by the relevant site, for example, here is link to revisions history of your question on meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/28616/revisions. You can find more information on this in the posts linked in the [edit-history tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-history/info).

For comments, I'll add links to other questions which discuss this: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390) and [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234)

---

Regarding the answer you linked: [Math markup, diagrams, etc. — pointers please](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480#482)

> The page's source html can be seen from Firefox's Web Developer menu. This allows to see the MathJax, but other Markup formatting has been replaced by the text being structured using the html tags.

Yes, this is exactly how viewing source of a page is supposed to work. Since the linked question asks about math markup (MathJax), perhaps the suggested answer is not completely unreasonable. (Although there are other possibilities, which might be considered simpler.)

I will add that *some* html syntax works also in posts, so if you copy-past part of the html code of a question/answer/comment (rather than trying to convert it to MarkDown), there's a good chance that it will display correctly.

For example this is what I get viewing source of this page from one paragraph in your question:

`<a href="https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/482/569197">This answer</a> says to right-click and select <code>Show source</code>. It looks like this method doesn't exist anymore, using Firefox at least.`

> [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/482/569197) says to right-click and select `Show source`. It looks like this method doesn't exist anymore, using Firefox at least.

Another possible interpretation of that answer is that the answerer meant Show Math As/TeX Commands in the MathJax context menu. (Which you get after right click on a renderer formula.) I will add a link to an answer about a different issue which contains a screenshot: [Simple Alignment to the Left](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18889#18890).

Comment: Tried the ones for the comments. That works.

Comment: Will have to wait for the right opportunity to see if posts with an edit awaiting approval allows to see the source through the revision history.