# How to view LaTeX source (mobile)?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, mobile-web

On mobile, how do you view the source of a question/answer so that you can see the LaTeX markup?

I'm using Google Chrome on a OnePlus (Android) phone.

Comment: The process is same as on desktop. Just need to emulate right click by touching and holding the mathjax part and you can see the mathjax menu. Use "Show Math as" followed by "TeX commands".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It's basically for the OP to clarify what the mean - but I'll point out that you're describe how to view a source of *a single equation*. The OP says "source of  a question/answer" (n [the original revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/35326/1)) - which makes it sound as asking for the whole post, including both MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: in that case one can edit the post and see markdown. However if my intent is to copy paste some tex code I prefer mathjax menu.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that won't work on Meta if you don't have the "edit question and answers" privilege (unlocked at 2k reputation). It also won't work on the main site if there's already another suggested edit pending review on that post.

Comment: Mailbox: As you see from the comments, there are several possible interpretation of the question - maybe you could clarify, whether you want both MarkDown and MathJax - or whether only MathJax is important for you.

Comment: You can check some older posts, such as: [Viewing markup of question/answer/comment, of one for which is editing is not allowed.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28616). This recent post is about comments - but some of those things should work for answers: [How to copy page content including all TeX commands](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35201). (Personally I do not use the site on any mobile device - so I do not know which f those methods will work on mobile.)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm replying to your first comment. On my device (iPad), long press results in no menu to come. What should I do?

Comment: @youthdoo Unfortunately, there is no way to bring up the MathJax contextual menu on an iPad; see the [answer to "How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30860/915354) for more details.